# WebApplicationFactory and TestServer in integration tests for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, quartz-scheduler

I have two integ test classes defined as below. When I run tests in ApiControllerIT, all runs successfully. The same for FoundationControllerIT. However, when I run both together (by running the enclosing folder), tests fail.

The error message is:

> Scheduler with name 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' already exists.

I have this definition in my Startup.cs file:

```cs
services.AddSingleton (IHostedService, QuartzHostedService);
```

So obviously this line causes the issue (if I remove this line, all testing together runs OK).  So my question is - I'm a newbie from Java.. so I don't have a very good insight into .NET Core Integ test framework, but my understanding is - TestServer is created for each of test classes, e.g. One TestServer for ApiControllerIT, and the other for FoundationControllerIT. Is this incorrect? I'm just frustrated how come I'm getting a message:

> Scheduler with name 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' already exists.

when I run two separate test classes?? How come the TestServers interfere each other?

```cs
public class ApiControllerIT : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public ApiControllerIT(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    
    // tests ...

}

public class FoundationControllerIT : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public FoundationControllerIT(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    
    // tests ...

}
```

Comment: Why didn't use services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>(); ?

Comment: I tried.. did the same.

Answer (score 4):

I might a bit late on this but I also had this problem and it might still be useful for others in the future.

The problem comes because the WebApplicationFactory will create two instances of your `Startup` class. This is drastically different from your normal service start, where you only have one instance of `Startup`.

(It might be a bit different in your case, but I am using a Singleton instance to create and manage my Schedulers throughout my application.)

The WebApplicationFactory also calls `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` on both of them. So even your singletons will be there twice, one for each `Startup` instance.  This is not a problem because the `Startup` instances will have their own ServiceProvider. It only comes to problems if (multiple) singleton instances access the same static properties of something. In our case, this is the `SchedulerBuilder` using `SchedulerFactory` using [SchedulerRepository](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/35b8532dc005af2fc907b6d2516c2e4bf40f833b/src/Quartz/Impl/SchedulerRepository.cs) within Quartz, which is a >real< singleton and uses this code:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Gets the singleton instance.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The instance.</value>
public static SchedulerRepository Instance { get; } = new SchedulerRepository();
```

This means that your independent Singleton classes still use the same `SchedulerRepository` within Quartz, which explains why you get the exception.

---

Depending on what you are testing within your tests you have some options to tackle this issue.

1. The `SchedulerRepository` has a lookup method, which you could use to check if the Scheduler was already created by another instance: `public virtual Task<IScheduler?> Lookup(string schedName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)` - So you either just take the existing Scheduler or you generate another one with a different name
2. Catch the exception and do nothing. (this only really makes sense if your tests do not need Quartz, which is probably unlikely but I still wanted to list this option)

I cannot tell you what makes most sense in your case as this is completely dependent on what your application does and what you want to test, but I will probably stick with one variant of option 1.